# How to avoid adding duplicate Data into Class Arraylist in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to add new object of `Person` class into arraylist. But I should avoid adding **duplicate data with only one attribute of Person class**. To be more precise Every Person has unique *clientId*. I need to check same clientIds should not be added into arraylist. When I try to add new Person Info with same clientId arraylist should just skip it. It does not matter other attributes are same except clientId. I am trying to check without looping Arraylist. I need more better way. I tried to use Set, But Set checks whole object. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Person {

    private String clientId;
    private Integer age;
    private String name;

    public Person() {
    }


    public Person(String clientId, Integer age, String name) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }



    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

```
public class ManagePeople {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Person> perArrayList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Person person;
        perArrayList.add(new Person("12", 100, "Tom"));
        perArrayList.add(new Person("14", 124, "Harold"));
        perArrayList.add(new Person("13", 234, "Petty"));
        perArrayList.add(new Person("15", 244, "Pedro"));
        perArrayList.add(new Person("16", 125, "Harry"));

    }

}
```

Comment: How about a `Map<String, Person>` where the String (the map key) is the clientId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the following steps:

1. Override `equals()` method (you should also override `hashCode()` along with `equals()`) in `Person` to return `true` when the `clientId` is same.

   ```
   class Person {
       private String clientId;
       // Other attributes
       // Constructor(s), getters, setters and other methods

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           return Objects.hash(clientId);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
           Person other = (Person) obj;
           return this.clientId.equals(other.clientId);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use a `Set` instead of `ArrayList`. The set will automatically discard the duplicate record (having same `clientId` as one of the existing records in the set) at the time of adding the record to it.

   ```
   Set<Person> personSet = new HashSet<Person>();
   personSet.add(new Person("12", 100, "Tom"));
   personSet.add(new Person("14", 124, "Harold"));
   personSet.add(new Person("13", 234, "Petty"));
   personSet.add(new Person("15", 244, "Pedro"));
   personSet.add(new Person("16", 125, "Harry"));
   personSet.add(new Person("16", 130, "Henry"));
   ```

   The record `new Person("16", 130, "Henry")` will automatically be discarded 
   because it has the same `clientId` as one of the existing records. You can 
   verify it by printing `personSet`.

**Further reading:** [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Comment: Can you show Implementation of equals() method inside Person class which checks clientId

Comment: I have added equals method in my Person class you posted. But anyway it is allowing duplicates. Should I check equals result when adding data?

Comment: @Abdusoli - When you will try to add a record with existing `clientId`, it will be automatically rejected. You do not have to implement anything for this.

Comment: it stills allowing duplicates. I tried this data ```perArrayList.add(new Person("16", 214, "Jimmy")) ``` clientId is same but name and age are different

Comment: No, it will discard `new Person("16", 214, "Jimmy")` automatically. Have you copied and pasted the code of my `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods as it is? Have you used `Set` instead of `ArrayList` as I've used?

Comment: Updated my code above but it is allowing to add clientId 16  two times

Comment: Should I change anything?

Comment: @Abdusoli - I've corrected the problem. I'd left `name` and `age` inside my `hashCode()` method by mistake. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Thanks now it is working fine. Now I need to learn how hashCode() and equals(Object obj)  functions working together

Answer (score 1):

Use HashMap and clientId as a key and value as your Person object. Map will not allow to add duplicte key.

```
HashMap<String, Person> tne = new HashMap<String, Person>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Set** instead of **ArrayList**, since **Set** allows to store only unique objects you can avoid duplicates.

```
Set<Person> perArrayList = new HashSet<>();

Person person;
perArrayList.add(new Person("12", 100, "Tom"));
perArrayList.add(new Person("14", 124, "Harold"));
perArrayList.add(new Person("13", 234, "Petty"));
perArrayList.add(new Person("15", 244, "Pedro"));
perArrayList.add(new Person("16", 125, "Harry"));
```

Comment: But How can I implement Set in this case. I could not do that.

Comment: added example please check

Comment: @DilliBabuKadati - This will fail to achieve the objective until `Person` has `equals` method to return `true` when `clientId` is the same.